# How to easily call predict on tf.estimator?

Tags: tensorflow

Function is defined with a case for MODE PREDICT. But how can you call it? Do you need to create input_fn just for predict?

Comment: Generally yes. What have you tried?

Comment: It works (to create a predict_input_fn) just seems clunky. I guess people wrap all this up in a class or something.